# dynamoDB update-item python boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a column in DynamoDB table which will be of the following type:
{"History": {"L": [{"M": {"id": {"S": "id"}, "Flow": {"L":[{"S": "test2"}]},"UUID": {"S": "1234"}}}]}}

[image: This is the History Column structure]

Column History is of type 'List' in which each list element is a map with 3 values - id (string), Flow (List), uuid (String)

My code would trigger update-item multiple times and all I want is, given the same id and uuid, new values are to be appended into the Flow list without disturbing anything else.

I have referred the documentation but unable to figure out how to write the UpdateExpression.

My existing code is as below:

```
response_update = client.update_item(
    TableName = 'tableName',
    Key = {
    'k1': {
    'S': 'v1'
    },
    'k2': {
    'S': 'v2'
    }
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET History=list_append(if_not_exists(History, :empty_list), :attrValue)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {":attrValue" :{"L":[ { "M" : { "id" : { "S" : "123" }, "UUID" : { "S" : "uuid123" }, "Flow" : { "L" : [ { "S" : "now2" } ] } } } ]},":empty_list":{"L":[]}})
```

With this code, each time I trigger the update function, a new element in getting appended in History list. Instead, I need my desired string to be appended to the Flow list.

Please let me know how the expression should be.